# Use dataframe name in dataframe.query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

df1

```
Company     Region  ID
Walmart     North   1
Walmart     North   2
OneStore    North   3
OneStore    North   4
OneStore    South   4
Walmart     South   4
OneStore    West    4
Walmart     East    5
```

df2

```
Company     Region  ID  Sales
Walmart     North   1   100
Walmart     North   1   150
Walmart     North   1   50
Walmart     North   2   400
OneStore    North   3   250
OneStore    North   3   150
OneStore    North   4   200
OneStore    South   4   300
Walmart     South   4   100
Walmart     South   4   250
OneStore    West    4   350
OneStore    West    4   100
Walmart     East    5   300
Walmart     East    5   400
```

Final output required

df1

```
Company     Region  ID  Sales
Walmart     North   1   300
Walmart     North   2   400
OneStore    North   3   400
OneStore    North   4   200
OneStore    South   4   300
Walmart     South   4   350
OneStore    West    4   450
Walmart     East    5   700
```

then i want to use a query like

```
df2.query("(df2['Company']==df1.at[0,'Company'])&(df2['Region']==df1.at[0,'Region'])&(df2['ID']==df1.at[0,'ID'])")['Sales'].sum()

but i get an error: **UndefinedVariableError: name 'df2' is not defined**
```

if df2 is removed from query

```
df2.query("(Company==df1.at[0,'Company'])&(Region==df1.at[0,'Region'])&(ID==df1.at[0,'ID'])")['Sales'].sum()

UndefinedVariableError: name 'df1' is not defined
```

if i use

```
df2.loc[(df2['Company']==df1.at[0,'Company'])&(df2['Region']==df1.at[0,'Region'])&(df2['ID']==df1.at[0,'ID']),'Sales'].sum()
```

then i get required result, (300 for first row)

but i want to use query function as this is a sample data and i work with a large dataset where columns vary so i generate a query based on columns like

```
'&'.join("(df2['%s']==df1.at[0,'%s'])" % x for x in ['col1', 'col2', . . . . ])
```

How can i make the query to work for this condition

***Update:***

*Thanks to [Emma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956135/emma) for merge & groupby,*

i got the output dataframe as required

```
df_1
Company     Region  ID  Sales
OneStore    North   3   400
OneStore    North   4   200
OneStore    South   4   300
OneStore    West    4   450
Walmart     East    5   700
Walmart     North   1   300
Walmart     North   2   400
Walmart     South   4   350
```

Now i have another dataframe

df3

```
Company     Region  ID  Stock   Units
Walmart     North   1   Full        5
Walmart     North   1   Full        7
Walmart     North   2   Full        4
Walmart     North   2   Restock     26
Walmart     North   2   Restock     34
OneStore    North   3   Full        2
OneStore    North   3   Restock     26
OneStore    North   4   Full        3
Walmart     South   4   Full        5
Walmart     South   4   Restock     74
OneStore    West    4   Full        9
OneStore    West    4   Full        7
OneStore    West    4   Restock     53
OneStore    West    5   Full        2
Walmart     East    5   Full        2
Walmart     East    5   Full        1
Walmart     East    5   Restock     36
```

I need to get the sum of units where stock staus is restock and add this data to new column in df_1, i'm trying to use groupby by filtering df3 where stock status is restock, buy i'm getting error

```
df = df_1.merge(df3, on=['Company', 'Region', 'ID'], how='left')
df_1.loc[:,'Units_req'] = df[df['Stock']=='Restock'].groupby(['Company', 'Region', 'ID', 'Sales', 'Profit'])['Units'].sum()

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Please help with best approach to this problem, i still have to add data from different tables based on multiple conditions, i still find it easy if anyone could help on how to use dataframe names in dataframe.query

Comment: Does it have to be `query`?   You can do this easily with `merge` and `groupby` aggregation.

Comment: Can you give a code example for merge and groupby

Comment: is it not possible to use query for this condition

Comment: I didn't investigate enough for the `query` option but what you are trying to do is simpler with `groupby` aggregation.

Comment: columns will be varied, so i store column names in a list & then construct query from list of columns to compare, is it possible to use column names from a list with groupby

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the 2 dataframes first, then aggregate on group.

```py
# This will merge the Sales information to the first dataframe.
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Company', 'Region', 'ID'], how='left')

# Then, you can group by the Company, Region, and ID and aggregate the Sales.
df = df.groupby(['Company', 'Region', 'ID']).Sales.sum().reset_index()
```

Or you can do this in 1 shot.

```py
df = (df1.merge(df2, on=['Company', 'Region', 'ID'], how='left')
      .groupby(['Company', 'Region', 'ID']).Sales.sum()
      .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try

Comment: it worked, but i got another requirement & its a bit confusing, i have updated the original question above, is there any possibility that i can use dataframe name in query